# Connection between Charles and Smartphone

Tags: mac

I've googled that problev a lot, but didn't find an answer, which works in my case.

I have Xiaomi Mi5 and try to debug it using Charles. I have Mac.
The problem is that Charles always tells me:
"Client SSL handshake failed: An unknown issue occurred processing the certificate (certificate_unknown). You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu."

I already installed root certificate for Mac and for Xiaomi, but still same mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a step-by-step guide to intercept https traffic for android apps using Charles debug proxy.

https://medium.com/@Mayank.Grover/intercept-ssl-traffic-to-perform-penetration-testing-on-android-apps-using-charles-debug-proxy-59211859d22f

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.